# Pandas: Passing format options into functions

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I want to extract coordinates from postcodes as a new df column.

The functionality from the `geopy` module is:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode('%s tn6 3rn')

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(51.0459837, 0.2192646)
```

My function to apply to this to a single value works:

```
def pcodeToCoor(x):
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    location = geolocator.geocode(x)
    return ((location.latitude, location.longitude))

pcodeToCoor('%s tn6 3rn')
(51.0459837, 0.2192646)
```

But when passing the function to a test df:

```
    name    postcode
0   jd      tn6 3rn
1   hf      en6 1dg
2   ss      sw17 0ju

df['coordinate'] = df['postcode'].map(pcodeToCoor)
```

I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude`. Note I can recreate this error by removing `%s` from the basic api functionality.

The question is, how do I use `%s` in my function? I imagine the answer's very simple but nothing I've tried works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this if you are going to use this function consistently this way, or you code code a check to see if your string starts with "%s".

```
def pcodeToCoor(x):
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    location = geolocator.geocode('%s '+x)
    return ((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

## Edit:

```
def pcodeToCoor(x):
    if x[0:2] != '%s':
        x = '%s ' + x 
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    location = geolocator.geocode(x)
    return ((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

Test:

```
pcodeToCoor('%s tn6 3rn')
```

Output:

```
(51.0459837, 0.2192646)
```

Test 2:

```
df['postcode'].map(pcodeToCoor)
```

Output:

```
0     (51.0459837, 0.2192646)
1    (51.7206134, -0.2042041)
2    (51.3866947, -0.1800573)
Name: postcode, dtype: object
```